# How to Remove the Stretch at the End of ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, stretch

How should I remove the stretch at the end of a listview?

[image]

Comment: post xml you use for this screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in your xml , property of ListView like this:-

```
 android:fadingEdge="none"

 android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: @Alireza you want to remove fading edge of list view when we are on top of the list or bottom of the list right !!!!

Comment: @Alireza i edited my answer . add this property also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in xml :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Default Listview there are some limitation Exspecially when using rtl languages
so Create a custom listview